# How to load a Groovy script from a git repo in a Jenkinsfile that is in a different git repo

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

So I have a groovy script called "deployer.groovy" that is in a git repository called "jenkins-pipeline-library". (https://github.com/xyzDev/jenkins-pipeline-library) there is nothing else in this repository just this groovy file in the main branch.

Also, I have a Jenkinsfile that is in a different git repository. I cannot put both of these file in a same Git repository.

*(because im not allowed to, the idea is to be able to run this deployer.groovy by using Jenkinsfile so that people dont see the content of the deployer.groovy but be able to use it)*

I am trying to load this deployer.groovy in my Jenkinsfile and then run it.

Is there any way to do this? Please any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to use Shared Library to achieve that: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: I already have global shared library setup but still I cant load this groovy file

Comment: Can you move it to vars directory? Then In jenkinsfile you can use the functions from the groovy file like so: deployer.functionName()

Comment: I have moved it to vars folder. So I have two stages in the deployer.groovy, first is like this - stage('Test') and second is like this - stage("Deploy Internal"). How to run these two stages ??can i do deployer.Test() to run the first stage and then second??

Comment: Not really if you use declarative pipeline then inside Jenkinsfile you need to setup the stage and use the function from groovy inside the steps block like this: … stage('Build') { steps { deployer.build() } } .. - Do you have other stages inside Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much for your input I was able to solve the issue. The solution I did may be very childish but it works(at least for now). At the very start of the script I wrote def code() { //my entire code } so basically turned my whole code in a function then called it in Jenkinsfile like this deployer.code()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Official documentation**

[Extending with Shared Libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) is the documentation that I would recommend for you to understand and achieve what you need.

**Explanation**

*Jenkins configuration:* Go to `jenkins-url/configure` -> `Global Pipeline Libraries` in this section you can setup the library: [using libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#using-libraries), [retrieval method](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#retrieval-method)

*Library repository:* Shared library repository should have the `.groovy` files in specific folder structure, for your use case you need this:

```
(root)
+- vars
|   +- foo.groovy               # for global 'foo' variable
|   +- MyDeclarativePipeline.groovy  # for global 'MyDeclarativePipeline' variable
```

`vars/foo.groovy`

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def test() {
  // define logic here
}
def deployInternal() {
  // define logic here
}
```

`vars/MyDeclarativePipeline.groovy`

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def call() {
    /* insert your pipeline here */
    pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
            stage('Test') {
                steps {
                    // input the logic here or
                    foo.test()
                }
            }
            stage('Deploy Internal') {
                steps {
                    // input the logic here or
                    foo.deployInternal()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Jenkinsfile:*

```
@Library('my-shared-library') _

MyDeclarativePipeline()
```

*Note: instead of `MyDeclarativePipeline()` you can insert the `pipeline {...}` block which was defined in `MyDeclarativePipeline.groovy`*

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achive this.

### Git Submodule

Your `jenkins-pipeline-library` could be git-submodule in other repositories.

```
 git submodule add -b master https://github.com/xyzDev/jenkins-pipeline-library jenkins-pipeline-library
```

### Jenkins: Global Pipeline Libraries

On your Jenkins-Server under `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Pipeline Libraries` you can add your repostitory.

After that in any jenkinsfile you can use it like this

```
import JenkinsPipelineLibrary // Name depends on the actual name of the file
```

This is an example from a pipeline script I made:

```
 import utils.build.PipelineUtil
 
 PIPELINE_UTIL = new PipelineUtil()
 
 properties(
     [
         [
             $class: 'BuildDiscarderProperty',
             strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', numToKeepStr: '25']
         ],
         PIPELINE_UTIL.getReleaseTrigger('xxxxx')
     ]
 )
```

Note: The `PipelineUtil` is located in the repository under utils/build/PipelineUtil.groovy.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your input I highly appreciate it.